# Python; Encode to MD5 (hashlib) shows error: "NoneType"

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, encode, hashlib

I wrote a code that will generate random password for 5 times, and I would like to encode that passwords to MD5, but when I try to encode it, it will show an error that 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode' and I dont know how to change the code to avoid this error. Sorry I'm beginner in python... My Code is below. Thanks for help

```
import random, string
import hashlib

length = 6
chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

def ff():
    rnd = random.SystemRandom()
    a = (''.join(rnd.choice(chars) for i in range(length)))
    c = a
    return(c)

def ff2():
    for i in range(5):
        print(ff(),' ')


str = ff2()
result = hashlib.md5(str.encode())

print("The hexadecimal equivalent of hash is : ", end ="")
print(result.hexdigest())
```

Comment: Should that be srt or str?

Comment: oh, thanks for notice!

Comment: Whenever you see a `NoneType` error, your first thought should be that you have a function that didn't return anything. And please don't use variables that are the same as Python types such as `str`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `ff2` doesn’t return anything so `str` will be of type `NoneType`.

Comment: Your answer is more like a comment, perhaps if you added the correction to the code

Comment: @AhmedMasud It’s an answer to the problem. I cannot fix the code since there is no indication about what the code should do.

Comment: sorry for no-info. It should generate 5 random passwords, and encode it to MD5 and print it out. That ff2() function should loop the ff() function for 5 times.

Comment: @MarcelKopera encode them as one string or separately?

Comment: I would like to import that data to csv file after that, so if it would be possible, I would like that data separated with space, or comma, or anything

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, your ff2() function should call `ff()` five times but it should not print out the result. It should accumulate them in a string and return the string. Something like this perhaps:

```py
def ff2():
    l = []
    for i in range(5):
        l.append(ff())
    return " ".join(l)
```

Here we accumulate the results of the five calls to `ff()` in a list `l` and then
use the string method `join()` to join them together.
The above  returns a string that is the concatenation of the five strings that the calls to ff() returned, with spaces separating them. If you want commas as separators, just replace the `return " ".join(l)` with `return ",".join(l)`.